# Why is my NSString null?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I read several threads about this topic but I can't solve my problem. Please help me. I think I'm too stupid to solve my problem.

My Problem: I have a ViewController and I work with storyboards - I created a NNString property - NSString gets a value - then I wanted to print the NSString with NSLog out but I got always the value null

Thanks for help and sorry for this maybe stupid question. This are little parts of my code, because I think the whole code is to long to post it here.

ViewController.h

```
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *loggedinID;
```

ViewController.m

```
   @synthesize loggedinID,
   ...
```

First method a IBAction

```
   loggedinID = [jsonData objectForKey:@"id"] ;
```

Now the other method a IBAction, where i want tu use the property

```
    NSLog(@"%@", loggedinID);
```

Comment: Not that this will solve the problem but get rid of the call to `@synthesize` and change all of your references of `loggedinID` to `self.loggedinID`. Doing this will change your to actually use the property as opposed to the ivar directly.

Comment: The property name in your `NSLog` is different to the property in the rest of the code. Also since it is a property I would recommend using `self.loggedinID` rather than accessing the instance variable directly.

Comment: Your problem is probably being caused because either `jsonData` is `nil` or it doesn't have a value for the key `id`.

Comment: I recognized the false name in NSLOG. I typed here in stackoverflow the flase name, in my code it's loggedinID. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: No jsonData has a value, because when I put the NSLog in the first method where loggedinID gets his value I get not null

Comment: You can post the full code on http://gist.github.com and link to it from here.

Comment: Show more code. When you access it directly there are good chances that you mix up properties, their iVars, paremeters or even local variables.

Answer (score 0):

Like guys in comment says... First of all get rid of this `@synthesize` thing. Compiler do this automatically for you when you declare property. From now you should access your property by **mutators** (setter and getter)

```
self.loggedinID = [jsonData objectForKey:@"id"]; // Calling setter
[self.loggedinID stringWithString:[jsonData objectForKey:@"id"]]; // Seeter as well

_loggedinID = [jsonData objectForKey:@"id"]; // ivar
[_loggedinID stringWithString:[jsonData objectForKey:@"id"]]; // ivar as well
```

It's a good way to access your properties via mutators. Only good place, for me, to use ivar are initializers.

Second, check this `jsonData`... This could be the problem of null in your string property.

Last, at the beginning you've declared `@property` called `loggedinID` and later you try to log `loggedinFirstName`.

Comment: I recognized the false name in NSLog. I typed here in stackoverflow the flase name, in my code it's loggedinID. The json I've checked with a NSLog and I get the right values.

Comment: So it's impossible that this sample isn't working. Everything is just fine! Maybe you've messed something else?

Comment: Thanks for your help :) the problem was the jsonData.

Comment: You don't need to write, @synthesize propertyName = _propertyName. This is what the compiler gives you automatically. There's no need to use "@synthesize" any more unless you override both the setter and getter (or the getter for a read-only property).

Answer (score -1):

At first: you don't need to `synthesize` anymore.

To answer your question: You are logging a different variable.

`loggedinFirstName != loggedinID`

Comment: I recognized the false name in NSLog. I typed here in stackoverflow the flase name, in my code it's loggedinID.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use @synthesize in ARC. Try putting value by prefixing self to your string Variable.

Also you can make the string STRONG instead of RETAIN.

Thanks

Comment: Totally unrelated to the problem. Also `@synthesize` has nothing to do with whether you are using ARC or not ... And for `NSString` I'd recommend neither `retain` nor `strong` (which are the same), but `copy` since it has a mutable subclass (`NSMutableString`) and `copy` makes sure that it always is a non-mutable string.